# Can I change terminal type used to login through SSH?

Tags: ssh, terminal, terminal-emulator

When I login on some particular server through SSH (which I do not have admin access to), I get the following error: `urxvt-unicode: Unknown terminal type` (I also don't want to change my terminal type permanently). It is important because depending on the terminal type I get different colors when logged in.

Is it possible to change the terminal type just when logging through SSH?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have root access to the remote box, install the package `ncurses-term`.
This will provide the `rxvt-256color` terminfo entry.

As a non-root user, you can also copy over the rxvt terminfo entries to
`$HOME/.terminfo/r/` on the remote machine, and export `TERMINFO=$HOME/.terminfo`.

```
ssh <host> 'mkdir -p .terminfo/r'
scp /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color <host>:~/.terminfo/r/
```

Comment: I don't have anything in `/usr/share/terminfo/`.

Answer (score 9):

You can also add following lines to your .ssh/config:

```
host *
   SetEnv TERM=xterm
```

Or whatever terminal you prefer.

You can set that also per host

```
host foo.bar
   SetEnv TERM=vt100
```

Comment: Imo this is the correct answer

Comment: Cleanest answer, but only works with openssh>=8.7 https://serverfault.com/questions/986847/ssh-behavior-of-setenv-for-term-variable

Answer (score 6):

after login you can execute something like:

```
export TERM=vt100
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually `TERM` is passed from your local environment, unchanged, to the remote environment.  If you set `TERM` on the local side when invoking `ssh`, that will do what is needed.

For instance, if the remote end has the terminal description for `rxvt` (but not `rxvt-unicode`), that would work well enough for function keys, etc.

Assuming bash or some shell which is POSIX-compliant, you can do this by

`TERM=rxvt ssh` *remotehost*

Doing it that way only affects the `ssh` command, not your local environment. I use this feature for handling typical machines which do not have the description for [`screen.xterm-new`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-new).  Depending on the remote machine, there may or may not be a suitable package which can be installed for the [full terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database).  Some (such as Solaris and FreeBSD) require the workaround.

Further reading:

- [The terminfo database is big—do I need all of that?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#big_terminfo)

Answer (score 2):

sshd process (from sshd(8) ) will read ...

```
6.   Reads the file ~/.ssh/environment, if it exists, and users are
allowed to change their environment.  See the PermitUserEnvironment 
option in sshd_config(5).
```

and

```
8.   If ~/.ssh/rc exists, runs it; else if /etc/ssh/sshrc exists, 
runs it; otherwise runs xauth.  The “rc” files are given the X11 
authentication protocol and cookie in standard input.  See SSHRC, below.
```

you might whish to edit `~/.ssh/rc` to setup TERM's value, as this file is read before shell's profile.